# load a html page in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I have a page name function.php, and another page called login.php

I like to make some function processing in function.php page... and then... when finish, redirect to a the login.php page... i dont what to include the login.php page into the function.php page, it's just wrong to see function.php in the url bar...

So what i what....

1. procession
2. redirect
3. Load the page just as a html/php normal page in browser

What command should i use to do that ? in php

Comment: have you considered header("Location: ") function call ?

Comment: `I like to make some function` Go ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this one:

```
<?php
function myfunction() {
//Your content
}
myfunction();
header('Location: login.php');
?>
```

For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: /url/of/login.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the processing is complete on the function.php page, insert `header('Location: login.php')` and the page will redirect. Also, for best practice sake, exit the script on function.php after the redirect with `exit()`